# As is , as it stands & as it is

Tags: difference, style

Is there a difference, if any, between *as is*, *as it stands*, *as it is*?

The FreeDictionary states the following:

[as it stands](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+it+stands): as something is now, without changes to it

> The law as it stands is very unclear.

[as is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+is):exactly as something is without any changes or improvements made to it.

> I'll have to hand this report in as is - there's no time to update it.

Obviously, they are interchangeable or the synonymous phrases. Maybe a small difference lies in a style of speech (formal/more informal speech).

[As it is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+it+is) looks way synonymous here as well (already, actually), but sometimes it is rather informal or spoken, imho.

Answer (score 1):

"As it stands" generally is used to reference something that *may* change.

> My opinion, as it stands, is firm.

"As is" generally refers the current state and it won't change because you are, for example, selling the item, turning in the paper, etc.

> I'm selling my used computer as is.

"As is" is used a lot in warranties or when selling something used, meaning it's being sold in its current state.